# Возможно продажа или возможна в ипотеку?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "Возможна продажа квартиры в ипотеку" или "продажа квартиры возможна в ипотеку"?

Comment: Ипотека - это ипотечный кредит, значит, "продажа возможна с помощью (или "посредством", или"через") ипотеки"

Comment: Мы же можем сказать "Я взял квартиру в кредит", почему тогда нельзя сказать "Я взял квартиру в ипотеку"?

Comment: По Вашей логике, может быть и "в ипотеку", как "в кредит". Но почему-то не нравится на слух. Ваше "через" кажется лучшим. Но как все-таки нормативно?

Comment: Но ипотека - это еще и под залог, почему тогда не "под ипотеку"?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: По-моему, неплохой вариант. Даже, я бы сказала, лучший, потому что самый простой.

Comment: Я бы с радостью сокласился с "купить квартиру в ипотеку". Продать в ипотеку почему-то вызввает резкое неприятие. Не могу понять почему. Похоже, субъективно, по аналогии с "продать в рабство". 

Хотя ипотека и есть рабство. Не для квартиры, правда, но для берущего ссуду...

Answer (score 3):

Возможны оба варианта в зависимости от того, на чем вы делаете акцент: на возможности самой продажи или возможности ипотеки. В устной речи особой разницы нет. там логическое ударение поможет, а в письменной, конечно, нужно выбрать правильный порядок слов. Хорошо бы знать и предыдущее предложение. Похоже. что это объявление. Тогда могу предположить два варианта. 1. Сдается квартира...Возможна продажа в ипотеку. 2. Продается квартира... Продажа возможна в ипотеку.

Я больше сомневаюсь в выборе предлога: продажа в ипотеку, под ипотеку или "посредством ипотеки" (как у Ленина). Встречаются все варианты, нормативного не знаю. Наверное так, как в законах.

Comment: Ох, не дочитал я сразу, когда свой писал...
"посредством ипотеки" - едва ли не правильнее всего, ео уж очень длинно.

Answer (score 3):

Все плохо.

ИПОТЕКА, -и; ж. [греч. hypothēkē - залог, заклад] Экон.
Ссуда, выдаваемая под залог недвижимого имущества; залог недвижимого имущества под такую ссуду. < Ипотечный, -ая, -ое. И. кредит. И. банк.
(БТС Кузнецова)

Первое значение не подходит сразу, это сама ссуда, можно купить на неё, но не в неё.
Давайте разбираться со вторым. Это схема продажи, т.е. речь должна вестись о ней. Возможно ли "продажа в залог"? Сомнительно. Скорее уж - под залог.

Таким образом из двух зол рекомендую третье. 
Продажа квартиры возможна **под** ипотеку. 
Или четвертое. 
Возможна продажа квартиры **под** ипотеку.
Что же касается вариантов автора, то они явно растут из выражений "в кредит", "в долг", "в рассрочку". Но "ипотека" строго говоря не является ни одной их этих возможностей. Это ссуда. В ссуду не дают и не берут. Её саму дают и берут.